# Running Projects Programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms

I was wondering if it is possible to open a second project (in the same solution as the first one) by code in the first project.

For example i have one form application project and another console application project.
The form application starts and when the user clicks a button i want the console application to run and the form application to stop.

Or could someone tell me how to delete my application .exe file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The projects don't need to be in the same solution to do that.  Just use `Process.Start` to start the executable for another application, and then close the main form to end the current application.

If you don't want to run the code as an entirely different process then it may also make sense to have a 3rd project that is a "class library" that the other two projects could add a reference to.  This would allow you to define common code used in either application, using classes that are generalized to be helpful in either project.

Comment: Thanks, but i am actually trying to delete everything that has to do with my application and having another project will add another item to delete.

Comment: @BoB If you want to delete everything then delete everything.  If you want your program to function as you described it then follow the proposal in this answer.  You can't really do both though; a deleted application can't function as you've described it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do; but Process class has Start and Kill methods that will let you launch / exit processes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx